# Card content not shown at card center when expanded text is present

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack widget with a column inside, and inside the column there are 9 Containers, inside each container there is a Card widget.

Here you have the code for the first and the second cards.

The only difference on both cards is that the first has an image, a text and a extended text.
The second has only image and text.

My issue is that at first card, both image, text and expanded text are not shown at the center of the card.

Output screenshot:

[image]

I would like to get all cards looking equal, with or without expanded text inside.

How should I change the code to get this as I want?

```
child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[

    SafeArea(

      child:
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(26.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Expanded(

              child: GridView.count(
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                primary: false,
                crossAxisCount: count,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card1 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => MisClinicas()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://../clinica.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Mi clínica',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                clinicaProvider.clinica,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent

                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card2 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => MiPerfil()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://.../miperfil.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Mi perfil',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card3 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Pacientes()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/pacientes.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Pacientes',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card4 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Agenda()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/agenda.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Agenda',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card5 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Chat()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/chat.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Chat',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card6 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Sat()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/sat.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'SAT',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card7 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Tienda()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/tienda.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Tienda',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Card8 Clicked");
                        Navigator.push (context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Privacidad()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/privacidad.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Privacidad',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green,
                      onTap: () async {
                        print("Card9 Clicked");
                        SharedPreferences prefs =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        prefs.remove('email');

                        clinicaProvider.removeClinica("");
                        Toast.show("Gracias por usar Capenergy", context,
                            duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                            gravity: Toast.CENTER,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xff01A0C7),
                            textColor: Colors.white);
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext ctx) => MyApp()));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://capenergy-app.com/iconos_app/salir.png',
                              height: 65,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Cerrar',
                              style: cardTextStyle,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expanded` widget take the remaining space in your column.

You have to remove it to get your widgets centered.

To help you understand your UI concerns, you could activate the **Debug Painting** mode.

Comment: The second one, in your card